# How to mount USB to Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, chromebook

The problem is that when I insert a USB, Ubuntu recognizes it on the desktop, but then it suddenly disappears and cannot be accessed from the files manager and basically acts as if it doesn't exist. I'm using an older Chromebook (I think an HP 14'') and I had to create an entire backway door through developer mode in order to even install Ubuntu.

My Chromebook has low storage space (16GB) and it currently doesn't have enough space to accommodate work. I cross posted this to reddit and they suggested I try the commands `dmesg` and `sudo fdisk-l`. Ubuntu recognizes that there's a removable device attached. I just can't find it anywhere. It's not underneath places or anywhere else in the files manager.

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a weird behaviour, something is not right there, I can think in either a hardware issue, driver issue (I have no experience with Chromebooks, no idea about the support, although it's supposed to be fully compatible with the Linux kernel), filesystem or ownership/permissions issue, or even a not fully supported filesystem...

Have you tried on the same laptop other USB drives? Do they work, or does it show the same behaviour?

And have you tried the USB on other computers? If it was a Windows drive, it would not be weird that the FS is corrupted (let's check later this, a FS scan, and repair would be required).

The suggestions given to you, **dmesg** and **sudo fdisk -l** are good suggestions. Remember to run dmesg before connecting your USB, but also after.

I think that, if it appears, the FS should be supported, but you can try to install whatever it is... **ntfs-3g**, **exfat-fuse**, **exfat-utils**, even **hfsplus** and **hfsprogs**, if it may have a MacOS FS.

To debug a bit more, apart from that, you can find the USB devices you have connected by running the next command before and after inserting the USB drive:

```
lsusb
```

or

```
usb-devices
```

The difference will be your device, and this might also check if your HW is fully supported.
The mentioned earlier is better to check the difference, but to see it in live, you can also run:

```
watch lsusb
```

Check if it keeps listed by **lsubs** or **usb-devices** there even after it disappears from your desktop (if it disappears, then it would be very difficult to test).

Some more:

```
lsblk
sudo blkid
```

If it stays, you can check all the devices that are mounted (and there will be a lot) by doing just:

```
mount
```

At this point, if the USB may have some Linux/MacOS FS, check who is the owner, the permissions, etc...
Probably something like:

```
sudo ls -la /media/<your-user-login>/<usb-device-label>/
```

Maybe you just need to change recursively the permissions (while the FS is mounted):

```
chown -R <your-user-login>:<your-group-often-same-than-user-login> /media/<your-user-login>/<usb-device-label>/
```

Just in case, you can check your groups with

```
groups
```

Permissions (in a Linux FS), it would be weird that it has no read permissions, but check your sudo ls -la result, and you can just do (if the files belong to you):

```
sudo chmod -R u+r /media/<your-user-login>/<usb-device-label>/
```

Extra readings: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-basic-file-permissions-and-ownership-in-linux/

If it were some filesystem issue, depending on the FS it has, you can run **fsck** or **fsck.** to correct... for example:

```
sudo fsck 
sudo fsck.msdos
...
```

More info: https://linuxize.com/post/fsck-command-in-linux/
You can also try the GUI tool gparted, a partitioning tool with some repair options... it is in the Ubuntu repos: https://gparted.org/

Partition and data recovery tools could be tested if there's some non-fixable issue in your FS... For example, I  have used in the past **testdisk** for internal HDs (https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), that should be in the Ubuntu repos.

```
sudo testdisk
```

Some guide here: https://www.simplified.guide/linux/recover-lost-partition-table

I don't think so, but it might be some FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) issue as well... Check if there are updates for your system / fuse packages -there should be like 3 when running:

```
dpkg --list | grep fuse
```